# How to figure out the light bulb part number?

Tags: headlight, jetta, bulbs

I have done quite a bit of research and still can't figure it out, so I feel stupid about this. I have also failed to take out the particular bulb myself, so I can't see back of the bulb. I need to buy one so I can bring to the repair shop.

I have a 2008 Volkswagen Jetta, and one of the headlight bulbs is out. There are two low beam bulbs, and one high beam in total on each side. I know that the low beam on the outer part is H7, and the low beam bulb on the inner part of the headlight looks smaller. But for some reason, looking at Philips or car parts websites, I can only find H7(regular low beam) or 9006 which seems to be the fog light. So how can I figure out the part name or number for that small low beam bulb?

[image: Jetta Image]

Comment: The car handbook usually lists the bulbs required.

Comment: That would be a good idea if I could find the book, but I ended up finding the part on the dealership website. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You may be able to find a pdf version of your handbook on the web - found one for my car and the full workshop manual as well...

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by going to a Volkswagen dealership website. I don't know why I didn't try this before! They had diagrams, so it was easy to figure out the part number.

https://parts.colonialvwofmedford.com/p/Volkswagen_2008_Jetta-S-Sedan-25L-5-cylinder-AT/Bulb-Lamp-Light/48722721/N0177535.html

Comment: The bulb you posted in the link I don't think would be headlight associated. It is typically used for interior lighting or side markers, not for headlights.

Comment: @Paulster2 The linked text shows the bulb is used in the "high" position in the car's headlight, which I presume refers to physical location in the headlight assembly and not to the aim or spread of the beam. This bulb type is indeed usually used in the interior of a car, or for license plate illumination, but is apparently used in this model Jetta as a side light or running light or accent light.

Comment: David is exactly right. It's a very weak light bulb used as a marker light in the headlight next to the high beam. And the low beam is on the outer side. It also comes on at the same time as the low beam, so I mistook it for the second low beam, but it doesn't contribute much to the lighting in combination with the low beam.